How to add content into txt/lcr that is ignored by players?
I'm trying to write LRC SyncedLyrics files per txt.
I was wondering if I could add something that the player will ignore that looks like a timestamp but isn't. It's for organizing the timestamps when a song has a refrain twice but with different endings each time, to keep track of in which cycle it uses what.
Sure I can just put xx inside and remove it when finished, but if one looked at it later it could get confusing.
So far I've seen it displays everything after a valid timestamp (numbers, letters, brackets), but is there something a player doesn't? Like comments in other programming places ( // or /* */ )
I'm very lowly informed about programming and have only found one website along Wikipedia about LRC via txt and though I couldn't find it anymore
An example follows, with two formats, a timestamp not in the song [99.99.99] and with xx but that wi displayed at the location of the previous timestamp.
I just feel like the 99 stamp doesn't look very pretty and more confusing, therefor I was wondering if a non-number solution is available
Thanks in advance c:
Example:
[00:29.00][00:41.00][01:22.00][01:34.00][01:59.00][02:11.00][02:24.00][02:36.00] 'Cause..
[00:32.00][00:44.00][01:24.00][01:37.00][02:01.00][02:14.00][02:26.00][02:39.00] I'm ...
[00:35.00][00:48.00][01:28.00][99:99.99][02:05.00][99:99.99][02:29.00][99:99.99] Land...
[00:38.00][99:99.99][01:31.00][99:99.99][02:08.00][99:99.99][02:32.00][99:99.99] If...
[99:99.99][00:48.00][99:99.99][01:40.00][00:xx.00][02:17.00][99:99.99][02:41.00] Land2
[99:99.99][00:53.00][99:99.99][01:45.00][00:xx.00][02:22.00][99:99.99][02:66.00] No...
as said,
I used [99.99.99], I haven't tried it yet but I am sure it works,
and [xx.xx.xx] but that will be displayed at the time of the block before.
I expected the brackets to be just ignored if not correct but apparently, they don't.
For the first, I assume they'll just not be displayed anywhere if the track is not longer than those 99+.
